# Call remote asmx service by JQuery always fail

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery

I want to use below service throw JQuery:
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry
But it only execute the error function, I tried below :

```
        function serviceCall() {
        var txtInput = $("#txtInput").val();
        var webMethod = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry';
        var datap = {"CountryName":JSON.stringify("Italy")}; 

        $("#divResult").html('loading...');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webMethod,
            data: datap,// { "CountryName" : JSON.stringify("Italy")},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp", //for Firefox change this to "jsonp"
            success: function (response) {
                alert("reached success");
                $("#divResult").html(response.d);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("Unavailable: " + txtInput);
            }
        });
    }
```

SO I receive Unavailable: Italy

Below is full page code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function serviceCall() {
        var txtInput = $("#txtInput").val();
        var webMethod = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry';
        var datap = {"CountryName":JSON.stringify("Italy")}; 

        $("#divResult").html('loading...');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webMethod,
            data: datap,// { "CountryName" : JSON.stringify("Italy")},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp", //for Firefox change this to "jsonp"
            success: function (response) {
                alert("reached success");
                $("#divResult").html(response.d);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("Unavailable: " + txtInput);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="text" id="txtInput" value="Italy"/>
    <br />
     <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: yellow;" onclick="serviceCall();">
    Click me</div>
<div id="divResult" runat="server">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help to fix that?

Comment: Please provide the error message you actually receive from the server. To see it, track the XHR request with tools like FireBug or the Dev-Console from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I can see several mistakes here:

- the **dataType** has to be **json**, *not* jsonp
- your payload (the value of **data**) has to be a json-object **entirely serialized**
- is your WebMethod a [ScriptMethod](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.de/2013/08/return-json-from-asmx-when-call-it.html)?

Can't exactly tell what is wrong though. I need to see the error message from the server.

Comment: As you can see, The link is global  : http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry
I am not sure if it ScriptMethod, but I think yes, 
Please can you make your script, and test that, I cann't get the error, However it go to fail/error ajax funcation.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't because I assume your webservice does not support cross-domain operations. You need to tell me the error message the webservice is giving you, not the message you're composing in your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

use the following example to call asmx method and any web method from any where else

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'PageName.aspx/SaveData',
            data: "{'radio':'" + input 1+ "', 'min':'" + input 2 + "', 'sec':'" + input 3 + "'}",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function ()
            { console.log('there is some error'); }
        });
```